# Pass parameter to Customer Voice survey in D365

Tags: survey, dynamics-365

We have imported the Customer Voice solution and configured the `Incident` entity to send surveys - the `Incident` record now has the `Send Survey` button displayed.

We are sending the survey as an Email template via Power Automate Flow and Send a Survey Action. The following fields are filled in said action: `To`, `Project`, `Survey`, `Email Template`, `Regarding`.

When a customer fills in the survey and clicks send, the data is stored somewhere in the database, correct? Our requirement is also to pass in the `ticketnumber` of the `Incident` (as if the customer filled the `ticketnumber` as an answer to a question) but we do not want to create another field in the form of the survey for the `ticketnumber`, but rather pass it on as part of the data that's being sent when a survey is filled.

Is this achieveable?

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable section of the survey. With it you should be able to store information like related record IDs and use them throughout your process. Whenever the survey response comes back, that information is stored as well.